# Find a basis for the row space and a basis for the column space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> By inspection, find a basis for the row space and a basis for the column space for the following matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2& -2& 7 \\
0 &1& 3 &5  \\
0& 0& 1 &-6 \\
0& 0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In order to figure out the Row Space, I found the RREF form of the matrix.

[image: This is the RREF form of A.]

So, I got the conclusion that the row spaces of matrix A are these.

r1 = [1,0,0,-51]
r2 = [0,1,0,23]
r3 = [0,0,1,-6]
r4 = [0,0,0,1]

However, the computer tells me that r1 and r2 are not the right answer, and I don't know why those are not the right answer.

I need the right answer with reason. Thanks!

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is already in REF form. Hence we can form a basis using the original rows of $A$:

\begin{align}
R (A) &= \operatorname{span} \left\lbrace \operatorname{row}_1 (A), \, \operatorname{row}_2 (A), \, \operatorname{row}_3 (A), \, \operatorname{row}_4 (A) \right\rbrace \\
&= \operatorname{span} \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -51 \end{bmatrix} , \, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 23 \end{bmatrix} , \,  \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -6 \end{bmatrix} , \,  \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right\rbrace.
\end{align}
But this is not the only basis.

Answer (score 0):

standard basis $(1,0,0,0)^T, (0,1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,0)^T, (0,0,0,1)^T$ is a basis for both column space and row space of $A.$